# Catch oData errors from oTable.bindItems

Tags: javascript, sapui5, eventhandler

I have a table built up in JavaScript thus:

```
oTable.bindItems({
    path: oQuery,
    template: this.getFragment("<fragment>"),
    filters: aFilter
});
```

Is there a way to catch the errors coming back from the odata call in the same way when you do an `oModel.read` you can specify success and error functions?

This reference seems to not mention it: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation

Perhaps there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 methods to check for oData Failure:

1. attachMetadataFailed. (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#attachMetadataFailed)
2. attachRequestFailed.

Let's take up option 2 with an example ( as I'm sure you will have a valid oData Service).

Service: http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

**Note**: **Employees** is a valid Entity Set in the above Northwind service.

I will try to bind my table with a **wrong** Enity set name such as : **MyEmployees**.

Now, binding my table to MyEmployees will throw error which we need to catch. Below is the working code:

View:

`<Table items = "{/MyEmployees}">`

Controller:

```
        var url = "proxy/http/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/";

        var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url);

        oDataModel.attachRequestFailed(function(e) {
            console.log('request  failed');
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oDataModel);
```

Go ahead and try it. Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: callback for `attachRequestFailed` will be called for *every* failed request of odata model, not just for failed items binding. I had this solution in mind too, but it doesn't seem to be feasible one I think.

Comment: Yes this is the case @Dopedev. But this was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Rahul